# How to show 'Please Wait Loading..' Animated Gif in Struts1/jQuery app, between form submits?

Tags: jquery, struts-1

I've got a Java Struts1 app and I need a 'Please Wait' animation between form submissions.

I tried doing it in Struts using this -> [StrutsPleaseWait](http://wiki.apache.org/struts/StrutsPleaseWait) but if you use an animated GIF the gif freezes after the redirect.

So then I tried to do it with jQuery [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started) but I can't get it to work with IE(7), it doesn't recognise jquery after the ajax new page create.

There's loads of websites that have this feature so what is the best way of doing it?

This also got me thinking, do any of the java MVC frameworks have this functionality built in that works with animations?

my code extract for the jQuery solution is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = { 
                cache: false,
                type : "POST",                  
                beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {                        
                    showLightbox("pwait");                                  
                    },          
                success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {  
                    //$("html").html(responseText); //DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY IN FFox, changes the font sizes!

                                    //DOES NOT WORK IN IE, jquery not recognised on new page thats created.
                    document.open();
                    document.write(responseText);
                    document.close();  
                    hideLightbox("pwait");
            }                   
        };  
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);
    }); 
</script>
```

Thank You

Comment: Without knowing more it will be difficult/impossible to help. If it's saying jQuery isn't recognized then jQuery isn't being loaded--this should be easy enough to diagnose. That it's animated shouldn't matter, although with IE, it's difficult to say--but jQuery handles most of those browser-specific issues with regards to Ajax/etc.

Comment: Hi Dave, yes jQuery isn't being loaded in IE after the page is written with the document.write  . I'm surprised there isn't more info on the web about how to do this considering how many websites have it. thanks

Comment: It depends on how you're trying to load jQuery, IMO you're probably doing it wrong, but there's not enough information to go on--your question lacks almost all details.

Comment: just loading jQuery the normal way with a <script type src>, thanks for your help. i think this way of doing it is going to be too risky

Comment: If you're writing to the pages with document.write I don't believe scripts would be loaded if they're just in a script tag. Your work flow isn't very clear, though.

Answer (score 0):

use

> beforeSend

instead of

> beforeSubmit

like this

> `beforeSend: function (arr, $form, options) {
>       showLightbox("pwait");
>
>                       },`